# Android xml properties programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml

I am changing the style of my button like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)btBroadcast.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
btBroadcast.setLayoutParams(params);
```

How can I add these four rules above?

```
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:layout_width="20"
android:layout_height="20"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)btBroadcast.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
params.height = 10;
params.width = 20;
params.rightMargin = 10;
btBroadcast.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
btBroadcast.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
btBroadcast.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Ill accept this answer in 3minutes, do you know how to make this a little transparent aswell and an image from the drawables folder?

Comment: Add `alpha` to btn as in `btBroadcast.setAlpha(0.8F);`

Comment: Can you also tell me how to set a background image from the drawables folder?